# Pandas: duplicate columns, cannot remove them

Tags: python, pandas

I all, I have a strange and somewhat frustrating problem.

When I give the following command: `gpd_cinc_merged.columns`

I get the following output:

```
Index(['level_0', 'index', 'SU_gdppc', 'SU_gdppcl', 'year', 'US_gdppc',
       'US_gdppcl', 'year', 'index', 'SU_milex', 'SU_cinc', 'US_milex',
       'US_cinc', 'year', 'year'],
      dtype='object')
```

You may notice the presence of multiple `year` columns. They all have the same value and I would like to remove `all but one.`

However, I am unable to do so

```
gpd_cinc_merged.drop('year', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Removes all of them, but I need one of them to remain there. 
So instead I counted their index numbers, so I would remove `just one.`

```
gpd_cinc_merged.drop(gpd_cinc_merged.columns[[7]], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

However, this command also removes all of them.

```
gpd_cinc_merged.year
```

Returns a dataframe with four `year` columns with identical value. Yet I am unable to use the variable in a merge operation, as it returns to many values.

Does anyone know a way to reduce these 4 duplicate columns to just 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.duplicated.html) with invert `mask` by `~` for boolean mask and then filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with `loc`, before filter by columns:

```
c = pd.Index(['level_0', 'index', 'SU_gdppc', 'SU_gdppcl', 'year', 'US_gdppc',
       'US_gdppcl', 'year', 'index', 'SU_milex', 'SU_cinc', 'US_milex',
       'US_cinc', 'year', 'year'])

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=c)

df = df.loc[:, ~df.columns.duplicated()]
print (df)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [level_0, index, SU_gdppc, SU_gdppcl, year, US_gdppc, 
          US_gdppcl, SU_milex, SU_cinc, US_milex, US_cinc]
Index: []
```

**Detail**:

```
print (~df.columns.duplicated())
[ True  True  True  True  True  True  True False False  True  True  True
  True False False]
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks for your response!